# Connect Route::resource with existing model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.4 and I have created a controller with resources. Now I would like to  open the edit page in my app like the following:

`a href="{{ route('tasks.edit', ['tasks'=>$storedTask->id]) }}" class='btn btn-default'>Edit</a>`

In my view I am using:

```
Route::resource('/', 'IndexController');
```

However, I get back

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found when opening the link.

When looking into my routes list the URIs are emtpy.

```
+--------+-----------+------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI                    | Name             | Action                                                                 | Middleware   |
+--------+-----------+------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | /                      | index            | App\Http\Controllers\IndexController@index                             | web          |
|        | POST      | /                      | store            | App\Http\Controllers\IndexController@store                             | web          |
|        | PUT|PATCH | {}                     | update           | App\Http\Controllers\IndexController@update                            | web          |
|        | DELETE    | {}                     | destroy          | App\Http\Controllers\IndexController@destroy                           | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | {}                     | show             | App\Http\Controllers\IndexController@show                              | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | {}/edit                | edit             | App\Http\Controllers\IndexController@edit                              | web          |
+--------+-----------+------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

I guess that my model is not "*associated*" with my controller and therefore the `Route::resource` view.

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: the first argument to `resource` is the resource name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use resource route with just `/`. Change it to:

```
Route::resource('tasks', 'IndexController');
```